# Missing request mapping to controller. Spring MVC

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, servlets, controller

When execute request to controller, error 404 show.
I don't understand what I did wrong.

Below published web.xml, *-servlet.xml, controller class.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/golfing-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>golfing</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>golfing</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/golfing/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

Corresponding golfing-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vlad.home.controllers.*" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView render() {
        System.out.println("WAS CALLED CONTROLLER METHOD render()");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*")
    public ModelAndView others() {
        System.out.println("WAS CALLED CONTROLLER METHOD others()");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

Also in tomcat output console log missed mapped URL path to my controller, so it's strange.

```
мар 15, 2016 5:57:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
мар 15, 2016 5:57:26 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
мар 15, 2016 5:57:26 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 15 17:57:26 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
мар 15, 2016 5:57:26 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/golfing-servlet.xml]
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 328 ms
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'golfing': initialization started
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'golfing-servlet': startup date [Tue Mar 15 17:57:27 EET 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/golfing-servlet.xml]
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'golfing': initialization completed in 76 ms
```

I really don't understand where place of the mistake.

Comment: i think you are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in golfing-servlet.xml. Add and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now structure have some another view:

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-app-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jdbc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jdbc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

spring-app-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vlad.home.*" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:dataSource.properties, classpath:hibernate.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.vlad.home.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">${hibernate.c3p0.acquire.increment}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max.size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and jdbc-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vlad.home.controllers.or"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>
</beans>
```

`<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is need in applicationContext.xml